# Why do I have modification indices for free parameters?

Tags: goodness-of-fit, structural-equation-modeling, lavaan

Here is my SEM model;

```
modelQ <- '

    # Mastery measures  
    mastery =~ Q19.1 + Q19.2 + Q19.3 + Q19.4 + Q19.5
    CanDo   =~ Q19.6 + Q19.7

    # Social support measures
    capital    =~ Q35.1 + Q35.3 + Q35.4 + Q35.6 + Q35.8 + Q35.10
    validation =~ Q35.2 + Q35.5 + Q35.7 + Q35.9

    # Regressions on observed, dependent variables.     
    noSatisfaction ~ mastery + CanDo + coping + mentalDiag + health + needs + 
        married + capital + validation
    Depression ~  mastery + CanDo + coping + mentalDiag + health + needs + 
        married + capital + validation
    stress ~      mastery + CanDo + coping + mentalDiag + health + needs + 
        married + capital + validation
```

I have two measures with two factors each. Q19.1-Q19.7 and Q35.1-Q35.10 are indicators for those measures. I also have a lot of variables that enter the model directly, such as "health", "married", and so on.

The responses to the regressions are also manifest variables. So this is basically 3 multiple regressions, where some of the IV's are latent.

I ran modification indices on this and got MI's for parameters that should already be in the model. Here is a portion of the output, for the Depression variable.

```
          lhs op            rhs     mi    epc
1  Depression  ~        mastery    NaN    NaN
2  Depression  ~          CanDo    NaN    NaN
3  Depression  ~         coping 12.885 -0.127
4  Depression  ~     mentalDiag  6.990  0.186
5  Depression  ~         health  4.301 -0.074
6  Depression  ~          needs  6.764  0.182
7  Depression  ~        married  0.079 -0.022
8  Depression  ~        capital    NaN    NaN
9  Depression  ~     validation    NaN    NaN
10 Depression ~~     Depression  9.280  0.065
11 Depression ~~         stress  0.934  0.021
12 Depression  ~ noSatisfaction     NA     NA
13 Depression  ~         stress     NA     NA
```

I get why the mi for 'Depression ~ mastery' is NA --- that regression term is included in the model, so there is nothing to modify. But why do I get modification indices for 'Depression ~ health', for instance, and the others? I would have thought that the regression coefficient of health on Depression would be free, given the model, and there should be nothing to modify. Same deal with `Depression ~ married`.

I also don't understand why there is a MI for `Depression ~~ stress`, since that should also be included in the model.

I am using lavaan from R, but this isn't a lavaan question. It seems that modification indices do not mean what I think they do -- namely show what happens when you allow a fixed parameter to vary in the model. So what do they mean?

Comment: First, is Depression ~~ stress in the model?  Did you use the sem() command or the lavaan() command to estimate the model? I think they have different defaults.

Comment: I don't think you're wrong about MIs.  It's just that the MIs are estimates of what will happen. It doesn't actually free the parameter and run it again. I've not seen this in Lavaan, but I've seen similar things in Mplus, where it tells me to free a parameter that is free (or a parameter that would not be identified if it were free). MIs are only a guide.

Comment: I used sem(). Depression ~~ stress gets estimated by the model as I specified it. sem() supplies a lot of extra covariances automatically. So that should also be a free parameter.